# How to filter the filtered stream

Tags: java, jpa, filter, stream

I am learning Java8 with stream now.

I got List of CustomDto.
CustomDto has list of CustomDto1.
CustomDto1 has list of CustomDto2.

I need result like this.

```
List<CustomDto> response = data from read;
response.stream()
.filter(x-> x.getCustomDto1List.stream()
    .filter(y-> y.getCustomDto2List.stream()
       .filter(z-> z.getCustomDto2.getSomeColumn.equals("XXX"))
     )
)
```

Is it possible ? and If it is, How can I get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can but you should use method called anyMatch();

```
.filter(x-> x.getCustomDto1List.stream()
                    .anyMatch(y-> y.getCustomDto2List.stream()
                            .anyMatch(z-> z.getCustomDto2.getSomeColumn.equals("XXX"))
                    )
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I want the all list the customDto lists.

Comment: Then just use .map() instead of .filter().

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to find all objects which have a certain value in a nested list. Something like this?

```
response.stream().filter(x -> x.getCustomDto1List.stream()
        .flatMap(y-> y.getCustomDto2List.stream())
        .anyMatch(z-> z.getSomeColumn.equals("XXX")))
    .collect(toList());
```